# Перемещение данных

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Мне нужно прочитать данные из одной функции и передать их в другую. Функции объявлены так

```cpp
void Read(void * data, size_t len);
void Write(const uint8_t * data, size_t len);
```

Функции из сторонних библиотек и модификации не подлежат.

Такой код корректен?

```cpp
size_t len = ...;
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data(new uint8_t[len]);
Read(data.get(), len);
Write(data.get(), len);
```

Или можно как-то проще?

Comment: а `reinterpret_cast` тут зачем?

Comment: Не можно проще, а нужно. Зачем создавать умный указатель, а потом  его не использовать вовсе? Сразу передайте Read(new uint8_t[len], len) .  Вы точно знаете, что функция не удаляет массив?

Comment: @MaximTimakov Мой провтык. Функция принимала `uint8_t*`, а указатель был `std::unique_ptr<int8_t[]>`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan не понял. Т.е. объявить `uint8_t * data = new uint8_t[len]`? Умный указатель здесь для автоматического вызова `delete[] data`

Comment: Если функция удаляет массив или создает другой умный указатель с этим массивом, будут проблемы.

Comment: Нормально, если функция `Read` ожидает получить именно указатель на элемент массива из `uint8_t` и не пытается освободить память.

Comment: Сделать vector<int8_t> и всё. Если же либа пытается что-то там освободить, то в топку такую либу.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков и как потом с этим вектором работать? Ну размер я задам через `resize()`, а как получить указатель на данные?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Туть написано как: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если `len` невелико, то

```
{
    uint8_t * data;
    Read(data = (uint8_t*)alloca(len),len);
    Write(data,len);
}
```

Ну, а если побольше...

```
{
    uint8_t * data;
    Read(data = new uint8_t[len],len);
    Write(data,len);
    delete[] data;
}
```